# Read database password from Vault in grails app

Tags: grails, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am trying to read the database password from Vault so that it is not visible in Environment variables in grails 3. Previously we were reading all database configs from environment variables in application.groovy like below;

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
dbCreate = "update"
url = System.getenv("DB_URL")
driverClassName = System.getenv("DB_DRIVER")
dialect = System.getenv("DB_DIALECT")
username = System.getenv("DB_USER")
password = System.etenv("DB_PASSWORD")
}
```

Now I have a service that reads database password from Vault secret but I am unable to call that service function from application.groovy since it a config file. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Are you using spring-cloud-vault-config-databases as described in the docs? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.backends.database-backends

Comment: Show us the code

Answer (score 0):

you put it in runtime.groovy

```
def vault = new Vault()
url = vault.secret("secretKey")
```